# Activate form button subject to some condition

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a form with two combo-boxes and a button. I want button to be disabled initially and it should enable only when the user selects a valid value in both the combo-boxes.

I tried to disable the button using the form initialize sub-routine but the button appears to be active. What can be the issue? Also how to enable the button using if conditions?

```
Private Sub UserForm1_Initialize()

    Me.Shapes("ButtonName1").ControlFormat.Enabled = False
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("ButtonName1").Font.ColorIndex = 16

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a couple of mistakes in your code.

- `UserForm1_Initialize` should be `UserForm_Initialize`
- You can use `Userform.ButtonName1` to access the properties of your button
- Use `TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex` to access the text on a button on the worksheet

---

The code below should work

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    UserForm1.ButtonName1.Enabled = False
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("ButtonName1").TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 16
End Sub
```